# Aligning a portion of text in a table cell

Tags: tables, align, text

Is it possible to a align a certain portion of text in a table cell without changing the justification of the entire table? For example aligning the text that follows after (e = ). If someone already answered this question can you just post the link. Thank you in advance.

```
\begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{rX}
        $\phi$ = &capacity reduction factor of bolted connections subject to tearout\\
         = &0.70 for $\dfrac{f_{u}}{f_{y}} \geq 1.08$\\
         = &0.60 for $\dfrac{f_{u}}{f_{y}} <  1.08$\\
        $V_{f}$ = &nominal shear capacity of bolted connection\\
         = &$tef_{u}$\\
        &$t$ = thickness of connected part\\
        &$e$ = distance measured in the line of force from the centre of a standard hole to the nearest edge of an adjacent hole or to the end of the connected part    
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I think this would look better in a `align`-environment than in a tabular. But inside a `tabular`you could use a `\parbox` with a specified length, or use `\multicolumn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, if I've well understood what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, float}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{r@{${} = {}$}X}
    $\phi$ & capacity reduction factor of bolted connections subject to tearout\\
      & $ \begin{cases}0.70 & \text{for }{f_{u}}/{f_{y}} \geq 1.08, \\
    0.60 & \text{for }{f_{u}}/{f_{y}} < 1.08.
    \end{cases} $\\[4ex]
    $V_{f}$ & nominal shear capacity of bolted connection\\
    & $tef_{u}$\\[1ex]
    \multicolumn{1}{r@{\phantom{${}={}$}}}{where} & \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-0.8em}}$t=$ thickness of connected part\\
    $e=$ distance measured in the line of force from the centre of a standard hole to the nearest edge of an adjacent hole or to the end of the connected part
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a variant:

```
   \begin{table}[H]
      \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{r@{${} = {}$}X}
        $\phi$ & capacity reduction factor of bolted connections subject to tearout\\
          & $ \begin{cases}0.70 & \text{for }{f_{u}}/{f_{y}} \geq 1.08, \\
        0.60 & \text{for }{f_{u}}/{f_{y}} < 1.08.
        \end{cases} $\\[4ex]
        $V_{f}$ & nominal shear capacity of bolted connection\\
        & $tef_{u}$\\[1ex]
       where \quad\smash{\rule[-14.5ex]{0.4pt}{16.2ex}}\, $t $ & thickness of connected part \\
       $e$ & distance measured in the line of force from the centre of a standard hole to the nearest edge of an adjacent hole or to the end of the connected part
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey yes this is exactly what I meant. Any chance that the vertical line can be removed?

Comment: Oh! yes. Just remove the `\smash{\vrule …{16.2ex}}\,`. I added it  for both aesthetic and semantic reasons (this part of the tabular doesn't have exactly the same status as the beginning, as I see it).

Answer (score 1):

A `tabularx` nested in another `tabularx` seems to do the job.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}>{$}r<{{}$}@{}X@{}}
\phi = & capacity reduction factor of bolted connections subject to tearout \\
     = & $0.70$ for $\dfrac{f_{u}}{f_{y}} \geq 1.08$ \\
     = & $0.60$ for $\dfrac{f_{u}}{f_{y}} <  1.08$ \\
V_{f}= & nominal shear capacity of bolted connection \\
     = & $tef_{u}$ \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}r@{}X@{}}
  where $t={}$ & thickness of connected part \\
        $e={}$ & distance measured in the line of force from the centre 
                 of a standard hole to the nearest edge of an adjacent
                 hole or to the end of the connected part
  \end{tabularx}%
}
\end{tabularx}
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe simpler, use two distinct `tabularx` environments:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather*}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}>{$}r<{{}$}@{}X@{}}
\phi = & capacity reduction factor of bolted connections subject to tearout \\
     = & $0.70$ for $\dfrac{f_{u}}{f_{y}} \geq 1.08$ \\
     = & $0.60$ for $\dfrac{f_{u}}{f_{y}} <  1.08$ \\
V_{f}= & nominal shear capacity of bolted connection \\
     = & $tef_{u}$
\end{tabularx}
\\[1ex]
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}r@{}X@{}}
where $t={}$ & thickness of connected part \\
      $e={}$ & distance measured in the line of force from the centre 
               of a standard hole to the nearest edge of an adjacent
               hole or to the end of the connected part
\end{tabularx}
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]